# Highcharts multiple series with different start or end points

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Using HighCharts, I have 3 different series with datetime data in an area chart.  Some of data for each series may start or finish at different periods, resulting in some of the lines to just get cut off or start abruptly.

Is there a way in HighCharts to essentially "zero" the the missing dates, so the line goes smooth from start to finish across the chart? I could certainly fill in missing points and plot it, but seems like maybe this is a common issue that there's a built-in solution for?

Thank you!

You can see here where one series has dates that extend beyond another, how it just cuts off:

[image: chart with miss-matching data end points]

Comment: Did you try to use [ConnectNulls](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.connectNulls) ?

Comment: @Core972 I tried this, but no dice.  It looks like also this requires the data to actually have a `null` value, as oppose to just offset date periods.

Comment: Could you try to produce the minimal working example where the problem occurs, and provide us with it? Would be great to debug it by myself. Maybe you could just preprocess your data and put the `null`s where they would be needed, and then use `connectNulls` property.

Comment: What are you config options, and how are you providing the data? Need more info - a fiddle or other working example that demonstrates the problem works best. If the data is cutting off, it sounds like you have an axis max set that is preventing the display of the full range of data.